# Doxygen: make highlighted code of C++ have same color as Visual Studio

Tags: doxygen

We can use commands:

```
code{.cpp}    \endcode
\include Test.cpp
```

or markdown:

```
~~~{.cpp}

~~~
```

to embed C++ code into documentation.
But the color of highlighted code look so strange. How can I make it look like color in Visual Studio.

Output:

[image]

Expectation:

[image]

I use doxygen version 1.8.17

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Please define strange (images?). Did you have a look st the css possibilities?

Comment: The version is 1.8.17. Do you mean I have to define a css for HTML_STYLESHEET tag?

Comment: Hello @albert, I edited my post.

Comment: I meant the HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET

Comment: What is the content of HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It is the name of a stylesheet file with css settings overruling / adjusting / adding new settings for the items you want to see different. One setting could e.g. be ```span.keywordtype {
        color: #ff0000;
}``` but you have to familiarize yourself slightly with HTML / CSS.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you albert.